# My blender 4.0.2 freezes while these errors show (charset_normalizer)

Tags: python, add-on, error

Sometimes when I open my blender 4.0.2 (usually after restart of the PC), it freezes for a few minutes while these errors show (charset_normalizer)

This does not happen when I force close it once and then open it. But it happens, Can you guys help me find the culprit addon or setting? I have tried updated all my addons and removing old ones.

I can see two errors the most, this "charset" one and an "Attribute Error - NoneType" one

[image]

Comment: Hello ! I suggest disabling blenderkit, it looks like it comes from this addon.

Comment: Blenderkit actually works fine under 4.02. The version should display as 3.9.0.231123 under Preferences > addons as of today.

Comment: Its not blenderkit, its even happening without it. Any suggestions? I can see two erros the most, this charset one and an Attribute Error - NoneType has no attribute. these happen on startup.